# Работа Django с уже существующей базой данных MongoDB, как?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Есть проект, в котором уже существует готовая база данных со всеми юзерами и их настройками интерфейса для бота Вконтакте. Задача сделать сайт для проекта, хотелось бы сохранить всю имеющуюся информацию и работать на ее основе. Я нашел модуль, который позволяет работать с Mongo из Django. Но я не до конца понимаю, как сделать так, что бы Django не создавало новую базу данных на основе описанных моделей, а работала с существующей, учитывая ее структуру.

Answer (score 1):

Django умеет подключаться к уже существующей базе данных.
https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/howto/legacy-databases.html